# Ads kit integration encountered error 499 error in HMS Ads kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Ads kit integration encountered error 499
The log is as follows
Android Logs shows Country is not set.
2020-08-21 17:33:56.535 10043-10141/? W/HiAdKit.CountryCodeBean: fail to get grs countryCode
2020-08-21 17:33:56.535 10043-10141/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrl.Builder: countryCode:UNKNOWN
2020-08-21 17:33:56.535 10043-2254/? I/HiAdKit.ar: multicard device
2020-08-21 17:33:56.537 10043-10141/? W/HiAdKit.k: requestAdContent IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Try to insert SIM card in device and/or update HMS libraries to latest ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the country set on your phone：

**Settings->System&updates ->Language&input ->Language and region -> Region**

Select a country except China and the United States may help with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the log shows countryCode: UNKNOWN, means it could not get your phone's region/country.

Set phone's region and language from Settings ->System & updates ->Language & input -> Language & region

It works for other regions except for the United States and China.